# Callout lines drawn under other layer's labels

Tags: qgis, callout, draw-order

I'm using QGIS 3.22.4 and struggling with labels.

I'm having quite a headache trying to avoid callout lines to cross each other but now a new problem arise and it is that they are drawn as any other symbol in a layer, that is under labels.

So I have a map with a number of layers, some of them with labels. I'm using the Label z-index option to control label rendering order but surprisingly that does not apply to label callout lines. Any label from any other layer is drawn on top of them. This makes the result quite messy. Changing the blend mode for callouts does nothing.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't callout lines be considered as part of the label the same way that label background does?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to put too many labels on your map in the first place?

Comment: Actually there's not that many labels on my map but some tend to concentrate in some areas causing this kind of situations.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Could you represent some labeled values using symbology?